# Graphics in the paintComponent disappear after resizing the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, resize, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm a java beginner, & I'm creating a program that draws lines using the arrow keys, where the next line starts from the end of the first line.
Now, I created it, but the problem is that, whenever I re-size the window, the drawing disappears.

Here is my code:

```
public class draw extends JPanel {

    int up = 1, down = 0, left = 0, right = 0;
    int beginX, beginY;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        if(up == 1){
            beginX = getWidth() / 2;
            beginY = getHeight() / 2;
        }
        if (up > 0) {
            g.drawLine(beginX, beginY, (beginX), (beginY - up));
            beginY -= (up);
            up = 0;
        } else if (down > 0) {
            g.drawLine(beginX, beginY, beginX, (beginY + down));
            beginY += down;
            down = 0;
        } else if (right > 0) {
            g.drawLine(beginX, beginY, (beginX + right), beginY);
            beginX += right;
            right = 0;
        } else if (left > 0) {
            g.drawLine(beginX, beginY, (beginX - left), beginY);
            beginX -= (left);
            left = 0;
        }

    }

    public void drawUp() {
        up += 3;
        repaint();
    }

    public void drawDown() {
        down += 3;
        repaint();
    }

    public void drawLeft() {
        left += 3;
        repaint();
    }

    public void drawRight() {
        right += 3;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *paintComponent* should draw the current graphics of the component, not just what you want to add. So you now have two approaches, either to remember all lines and draw them all, or create a separate buffer to draw on as you generate the lines and use that buffer to draw on the component when it asks to be redrawn.

Comment: Can you please give me some info on the buffer, or give me some link to refer..
Thank you